# How to get the history in webview flutter package

Tags: flutter, dart, webview, package, history

I'm trying to display the history of the browser in a separate widget using webview flutter package

How can I access the history list to get it?

Comment: You should consider use [flutter_inappwebview](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_inappwebview), this lib has a method to get navigation history

Answer (score 1):

You can try to provide a callback function for onPageStarted property and store the urls via that function.

Comment: Actually the package stores links somewhere in memory, so Im looking for a way to access it different from storing it again

Comment: To get the WebView history, use the `InAppWebViewController.getCopyBackForwardList`  method, which returns the list of visited URLs and titles during the current session.